# Angular.js, equivalent controller writing that fails

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm starting with Angular.js and have a question; What's wrong with the second way to express the controller? Take a look at the jsfiddle below

http://jsfiddle.net/yDhv8/

```
function HelloCtrl($scope, testFactory, testFactory2)
{
    $scope.fromFactory = testFactory.sayHello("World");
    $scope.fromFactory2 = testFactory2.sayHello("World");
}

myApp.controller('GoodbyeCtrl', ['$scope', 'testFactory', 'testFactory2', function($scope, testFactory, testFactory2) {
    $scope.fromFactory = testFactory.sayGoodbye("World");
    $scope.fromFactory2 = testFactory2.sayGoodbye("World");
}]);
```

Any references that may be useful to understand what's going on will be appreciated,

Cheers,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything is fine. you just got confused. use `app.controller`

`myApp` is the module name, not a variable name.

`app.controller(......)`

Answer (score 2):

If you run this in a javascript debugger, you'll find that the variable 'myApp' is not defined.  You can either use the 'app' reference that you assigned to the original module call, or use the following syntax:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller(...)
```